# How to change Ajax generated HTML-Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I have Problems to change HTML content, which is generated by AJAX

This is the code of the page:

```
@model IEnumerable<WE_SRW_PeerNissen.Models.Reservations>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Übersicht Liste</h2>


<form method="post" action="List">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchbar" placeholder="Search">

            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table" id="sorttable">
    <thead bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BookingNr)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Arrival)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Departure)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Appartment)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Adult)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Children)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Total)
            </th>
        </tr>

    </thead>

</table>
<link href="~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sorttable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/OverView/loaddata",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "BookingNr", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Arrival", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Departure", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Name", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Appartment", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Adult", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Children", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Total", "autoWidth": true },
            ]
        });
    });

</script>
```

An example what is generated:

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="sorttable_filter">
     <label>Search:
           <input aria-controls="sorttable" type="search" placeholder="">
     </label>
</div>
```

And I think that was my best try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on(function () {
            $('#sorttable_filter label:eq(1)').text('Suchen:');
        });
    });
</script>
```

which I set below the AJAX script, I also tried to put it in the same script-Tag below to make sure, that AJAX is Executed

Comment: datatable has a settings object via which you can specify the text for buttons that it shows. Read the datatable manual. Regarding the reason your jquery selector fails - it is most likely that the element you target is not present in the DOM when the code is executed. Like I said, read the datatables docs.

Comment: when you're using `on(...)` aren't you missing the event parameter?

Comment: I am very new to java and jquery, AJAX. I am not bad in C#... for a Student. I have to use java, jquery, AJAX  once, but I would like to learn more about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments...

jQuery on() method binds function to the specific event, like: $(something).on("click", doSomething) and you provide there only a function, thus it does not know what event to bind your function to.

Then, eq(1) is jQuery method, but not a CSS selector, thus you'd like to use "label:first-child" (if you need the first one). It will, however, destroy input field in your example HTML, due to it is inside a label element, so you (probably) would like to have it outside. In the case when you're unable to change that HTML output you can use a dirty hack of "moving" input copy outside of label element... like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var labelEl = document.querySelector("#sorttable_filter label:first-child");
  var inputEl = labelEl.querySelector("input");
  labelEl.parentNode.appendChild(inputEl);
  labelEl.innerText = 'Suchen:';
});
```

What I don't like is the fact that document.ready() might happen a while before actual element appears, so you'd like to look for result HTML appearance at least...

Comment: Oh Thank you so much, maybe you saved me 1.0 in our Project (german system best mark)

Comment: This is surely off-topic but I'd suggest you removing namespaces while showing the code, due to some possible NDA. – Grüße aus München